# Programación en Maxima

Tags: matemáticas, maxima

Me han pedido realizar un ejercicio de programación en Maxima, pero realmente es la primera vez que escucho que se puede programar con Maxima. El ejercicio es este, espero que me puedan ayudar o decirme donde puedo encontrar recursos.

Definir la función

```
geometrica :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
```

tal que (geometrica a b c) es la lista de los términos de la progresión geométrica cuyo primer término es a, su segundo término es b (que se supone que es múltiplo de a) y los términos son menores o iguales que c. Por ejemplo,

```
geometrica 1 3  27   ==  [1,3,9,27]
   geometrica 2 6  100  ==  [2,6,18,54]
   geometrica 3 12 57   ==  [3,12,48]
   geometrica 4 20 253  ==  [4,20,100]
   geometrica 5 25 625  ==  [5,25,125,625]
```

Comment: Igual esto te ayuda http://eagle.cs.kent.edu/MAXIMA/maxima_toc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuve que instalar maxima, pero la solución que buscas podría quedar así

```
f(x,y,n) := if(x>n) then [] else append([x], f(y,y*(y/x),n));
```